# openapi-generator-maven-plugin generated BigDecimal properties without the proper imports

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, openapi-generator

I'm currently generating a model with [openapi-generator-maven-plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin), but when the model creates `BigDecimal` properties it doesn't add the proper import. For example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import java.io.File;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
//Missing import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
public class Response  {
    /**
     * No description provided
     */
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private Optional<BigDecimal> maybeValue;
}
```

When I added the import manually the model compiles successfully, but I think It will be generated.

I tried adding `importsMappings` in the `configuration` section like this:

```
<importMappings>BigDecimal=java.math.BigDecimal</importMappings>
```

As it is suggested [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4745).

And also tried this:

```
<importMappings>               
    <importMapping>BigDecimal=java.math.BigDecimal</importMapping>
</importMappings>
```

But the behavior is the same.

I'm using the openapi-generator version 5.0.0. And my current configuration it is something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/swagger.json</inputSpec>
  <generatorName>com.test.CustomJavaGenerator</generatorName>
  <output>generated-sources</output>
  <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
  <templateResourcePath>test/java/myTemplate</templateResourcePath>
  <apiPackage>com.test.api.v1</apiPackage>
  <modelPackage>com.test.model.v1</modelPackage>
  <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
  <generateModels>false</generateModels>
  <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
  <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
  <generateApis>true</generateApis>
  <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
  <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [#/8803](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/8803) the `importMappings` configuration is not currently working.

[This](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/commit/892836f772004e775b66e27bb553a41ef3c9e312#L3057) seems to be the relevant commit and it is included in 5.0.0+, so try the previous stable one 4.3.1.